# How do I make posititional arguments with trollop?

Tags: ruby

I'm using trollop to parse command line arguments, and I want to add some required positional arguments like `filename1` and `filename2` below:

```
usage: my_script [--help] [--some-option VALUE] [--some-flag] filename1 filename2
```

How do I do this with trollop?

Comment: Did you find out how to use positional argument with trollop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trollop is about parsing options -- things which may or may not be present.

A required positional argument is not an option.  To access your positional arguments, just look at argv.  If you use a mix of options and required positional arguments, trollop will take care of stripping out the optional stuff, and leave ARGV in a state where it contains only the stuff you care about.

If you run this example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'trollop'

opts = Trollop::options do
  opt :monkey, "Use monkey mode"                    # flag --monkey, default false
  opt :name, "Monkey name", :type => :string        # string --name <s>, default nil
  opt :num_limbs, "Number of limbs", :default => 4  # integer --num-limbs <i>, default to 4
end

puts "opts: #{opts}"
puts "ARGV: #{ARGV}"
```

Here is what you will get:

```
[~/tbear/bin]$ ./t.rb
opts: {:monkey=>false, :name=>nil, :num_limbs=>4, :help=>false}
ARGV: []

[~/tbear/bin]$ ./t.rb arg1
opts: {:monkey=>false, :name=>nil, :num_limbs=>4, :help=>false}
ARGV: ["arg1"]

[~/tbear/bin]$ ./t.rb -m arg1
opts: {:monkey=>true, :name=>nil, :num_limbs=>4, :help=>false, :monkey_given=>true}
ARGV: ["arg1"]
```

Notice how ARGV is the same in example 2 and example 3.

Answer (score 4):

Trollop also gives you the `leftovers` attribute, that [provides the same information](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/trollop/2.0/Trollop/Parser#leftovers-instance_method). Here's how you'd use it:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'trollop'
require 'pp'

p = Trollop::Parser.new do
    opt :monkey, 'Use monkey mode'                    # flag --monkey, default false
    opt :name, 'Monkey name', :type => :string        # string --name <s>, default nil
    opt :num_limbs, 'Number of limbs', :default => 4  # integer --num-limbs <i>, default to 4
end

p.parse

puts 'Leftovers:'
pp p.leftovers
puts 'ARGV:'
pp ARGV
```

Here's the result:

```
> ruby se_01.rb foo blarb -m
Leftovers:
["foo", "blarb"]
ARGV:
["foo", "blarb"]
```